# Creating a list of unique combinations in sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large Excel file with thousands of rows containing test data from. I have them sorted by identifiers in the columns and I am trying to figure out what duplicate tests have been run.

There are 5 columns containing data I care about for each row. Can someone help me write a VBA macro to find rows with unique combinations of these tests and generate a list of the different combinations present in the sheet? Ideally I would like this list displayed on a separate sheet.

I don't want this data in a pivot table because the table becomes too large to deduce any information from it.

I've played with the concatenate functions but because some of the columns are missing the data, it isn't doing what I need it to do. I attached the code I have been attempting to modify, which I found on a different post on here. I am having issues with the If statement at the end (I don't even think it is going to do what I want) because I get a type mismatch error. I'm new to VBA, so I am running into a lot of issues.

Thanks!!

```
Sub GetCombinations()

Dim sheet1, sheet2 As Worksheet
Set sheet1 = Worksheets("Data")
Set sheet2 = Worksheets("Sort")

Dim sStartColumn As String
Dim iTopRow As Long
Dim sEndColumn As String
Dim iBottomRow As Long

sStartColumn = "AS"
iTopRow = 6
sEndColumn = "AU"
iBottomRow = sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim Rng As Range
Dim sRange1 As String
sRange1 = sStartColumn & CStr(iTopRow) & ":" & sEndColumn & CStr(iBottomRow)

Set Rng = sheet1.Range(sRange1)


Rng.Sort Key1:=Range("AS6"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
         Key2:=Range("AU1203"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
         Orientation:=xlSortColumns, Header:=xlYes

Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer


j = 2

For i = 7 To iBottomRow

    If sheet1.Cells(i, 45) Then

        sheet2.Cells(j, 1) = sheet1.Cells(i, 1)
        sheet2.Cells(j, 2) = sheet1.Cells(i, 2)
        sheet2.Cells(j, 3) = sheet1.Cells(i, 5)
        j = j + 1

    End If

Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Sorry about that, first time poster! But yes, It is Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Instead of asking a bunch of questions about possible variations in your data layout, it sure would make it a lot easier if you just posted a sample of data, and your expected results after running your macro.

Answer (score 1):

**APPROACH:**

1. add a column that for each row, contains the concatenation of the 5 columns
2. have the code work from the bottom upwards, looking for duplicates in the new column

Say the data is like:

[image]

In **F1** enter:

```
=A1 & CHAR(1) & B1 & CHAR(1) & C1 & CHAR(1) & D1 & CHAR(1) & E1
```

and copy down.  then run:

```
Sub De_Dup()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    For i = N To 2 Step -1
        Set r1 = Cells(i, "F")
        Set r2 = Range(Range("F1"), Cells(i - 1, "F"))
        If wf.CountIf(r2, r1.Value) > 0 Then r1.EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

ending up with:

[image]

You don't even need to sort the data first!